# class template with operator overloading

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I'm trying to define a class template and an operator overloading:

```
template<class T>
class complex{
    public:
    T x,y;
    complex(T a, T b): x(a), y(b) {}
    complex<T> operator+ (const complex<T>& c){
        complex<T> s{x+c.x, y+c.y};
        return s;
    }
};

int main(){
    complex<int> c1{1,2};
    complex<int> c2{3,4};
    complex<int> c3 = c1 + c2;
    cout << "x: " << c3.x << " y: " << c3.y << endl;
}
```

This works fine, but if I change the definition of operator+ overloading to:

```
    complex<T> operator+ (const complex<T>& c){
        complex<T> s;
        s.x = x + c.x;
        s.y = y + c.y;
        return s;
    }
```

it reports a compilation error:

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'complex<int>'  
       complex<T> s;  
                  ^
```

So why doesn't the second definition work?

Comment: `complex<T> s;` -- Look at your code carefully.  Then ask yourself how you're going to construct a `complex<T>` with no arguments.  What's really surprising is that you're using a semi-advanced topic such as templates, but failed to see the elementary error of not having a default constructor.

Comment: BTW, you don't even need to introduce an `s` variable, even in the code that works:  `return {x+c.x, y+c.y};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
complex<T> s;
```

This attempts to default-construct an instance of `complex<T>`.

The problem with that is there is no default constructor for this instantiated template class. The only constructor you defined in your template requires two parameters, and they are completely absent here.

You can add some reasonable, default constructor (a constructor that takes no parameters) to your template:

```
complex(): x(0), y(0) {}
```